# How to redirect to a Controller/Action passing any URL parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement "returnUrl" functionality in my aspnetcore app but I am struggelling to find a way to dynamically pass the parameters to an action.

The process flow goes like this:

[image]

1. The user has bookmarked URL `https://localhost:44358/Secure/VisualizationFiles?viz=vizFilePlays`
2. the website checks if they are logged in and if not redirects them to **Home** controller's `Login` action to log in (passing the returnUrl)
3. after logging in the user is redirected to the originally requested URL above including any URL parameters

Right now the **Secure** controller methods use `ActionFilterAttribute` which intercept the incoming HTTP request and make sure the controller; the action and parameters get passed as returnUrl (or `reRoute` in that case)

```
public class NimsAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         var url = filterContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] + "/" + filterContext.RouteData.Values["Action"] + "?" + QueryString(filterContext.ActionArguments);
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" }, { "reRoute", url } });

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    private string QueryString(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            list.Add(item.Key + "=" + item.Value);
        }

        return string.Join("&", list);

    }

}
```

After the user gets redirected (from the secure controller) to the **Home** controller, we get the full `returnUrl` (i.e. `reRoute` URL) being passed

[image]

As you can see, right now I am doing some error-prone string manulupation to extract the `Controller`; `Action` and `url params` from the `reRoute` string. I would like to know:

- Is there a way I can pass the whole `reRoute` url to the `Redirect`?
- If the above is not possible, is there an alternative way to handle the redirect so that it is dynamic (i.e. the url parameters will be different as well as the Controller and Action)

Comment: What happens when you use [Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirect?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (instead of `RedirectToAction`) with `reRoute` as a parameter?

Comment: I did try that but that makes aspnetcore things that I am trying to redirect to action in the same controller - `https://localhost:44358/Home/Secure/VisualizationFiles?viz=vizFilePlays`

Comment: Can you try `return Redirect("/" + reRoute);`? The `/` should cause it to use the root url.

Comment: @JayFridge that worked! :D I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you very much! Please add as an answer, I will accept your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirect?view=aspnetcore-3.1) Method instead of `RedirectToAction`.

So in you case it would look like this:

```
return Redirect("/" + reRoute);
```

The `/` is there to go to the root url, otherwise the request would route relative to the current controller.